# Looking for bash script which can insert input from 2 files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, html

I have 2 files with different data. How can I put data in those files and print it? I was trying for loop, but it is only good for 1 variable.

```
FileA
https://xyx.com/test-posts/
https://www.abc.com/temp-article/

FileB
xyx.com
abc.com
```

I want to achieve something like below

Sample

```
<a href="https://xyx.com/test-posts/">xyx.com</a>
<a href="https://www.abc.com/temp-article/">abc.com</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -- you need to provide a lot more details about what you're doing: what are your input files and what is your desired output?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show us i) a few lines of each of your two input files and ii) the output you want to get from those example lines. We can't help you manipulate data you don't show.

Comment: What does file B have to do with anything? It seems to me that the output could be generated using only file A?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for checking this. Please let me know how we can achieve that with only A file?

Comment: It looked to me like the target domain was simply repeated in the link text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$ paste FileA FileB | awk '{print "<a href=\"" $1 "\">" $2 "</a>"}'
<a href="https://xyx.com/test-posts/">xyx.com</a>
<a href="https://www.abc.com/temp-article/">abc.com</a>
```

*Note: you would need to do something more sophisticated (e.g. selecting a different delimiter for both `paste` and `awk`) if your file entries may contain whitespace - I assume that is not the case here since they are URLs*

Comment: Great! Working like charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ while read -r url && read -r domain <&3; do printf '<a href="%s">%s</a>\n' "$url" "$domain"; done <FileA 3<FileB
<a href="https://xyx.com/test-posts/">xyx.com</a>
<a href="https://www.abc.com/temp-article/">abc.com</a>
```

Or, as you would write it in a script:

```
while read -r url && read -r domain <&3; do
    printf '<a href="%s">%s</a>\n' "$url" "$domain"
done <FileA 3<FileB
```

This is a `while` loop that loops until either of two `read` calls fails to read a complete line.  The first `read` reads the URL from `FileA` while the second `read` reads the domain from `FileB` (via file-descriptor 3).

The output is handled by a `printf` call that inserts the read data into a formatting string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

filea=/path/to/filea
fileb=/path/to/fileb

lines=$(grep -c . "$filea")

for ((i=1; i<=lines; i++)); do
    url=$(sed -n "${i}p" "$filea")
    name=$(sed -n "${i}p" "$fileb")
    printf "<a href=\"${url}\">${name}</a>\n"
done
```

`lines` will be set to the total number of lines in `filea`

We then loop through from 1 to n-lines and extract that line from each of `filea` and `fileb` using `sed`.  Then print the required `href` statement using that extracted data.